# The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file - VMWare Centos7

Tags: postgresql, centos, virtual-machine, vmware

> The process cannot access the file because another process has locked
> a portion of the file
>
> Cannot open the disk 'C:\Users\Umair\Documents\Virtual
> Machines\CentOS_pg\Windows 10 x64.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks
> it depends on.
>
> Module 'Disk' power on failed.
>
> Failed to start the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create the backup of virtual Machine Directory.
> 2. Remove *.lck files or move to another directory
> 3. Restart the VM.